In Recent Civicrm Update (5.78.0) No Contribution page not opening , it says Unable to connect with server . - Wordpress Site
I have Updated my Wordpress site Civicrm to 5.78.0 , Clear All things working fine but did not get contribution table is for specific user , it says unable to react server
I have tried , the clear cache .I also seen activity here my contribution shown. So i revert back so its working fine

There are more civicrm eyeballs at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/
